Laravel spatie activity log deep eager load of subject
Using spatie activity log I have multiple models that are logging activity, and an ActivityResource class.
inside the ActivityResource class im calling other Resource classes based on subject_type.
$subjectResource = match ($this->subject_type) {
    Profile::class => ProfileResource::class,
    Invoice::class => InvoiceResource::class,
    Payment::class => PaymentResource::class
};

i would like to eager load a deep nested relation from subject based on the the subject_type, this is what i'm currently doing.
$profile = match ($this->subject_type) {
    Profile::class => $this->whenLoaded('subject'),
    Invoice::class => $this->whenLoaded('subject.profile'),
    Payment::class => $this->whenLoaded('subject.invoice.profile'),
};

Then i'm doing this
$activities = Activitiy::with([
    'subject'=>['invoice.profile','profile']
]);
ActivityResource::collection($activities);

The issue is when trying to eager load the relation i'm getting an error
Call to undefined relationship [profile] on model [App\\Models\\Profile].

The question is how to conditionaly eager load deep relationships from polymorphic data?
